# Where can i put this rabbitmq consumer code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabbitmq, bunny

I have this code of a rabbitmq consumer using [bunny](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/bunny) that should listen to messages published to a rabbitmq queue and display a flash notice on the view whenever a message is consumed. The consumer is running in a different session from the producer though they are in the same application. The application uses a direct exchange which uses the message receiver's email as the routing_key. I would like when a message with a `routing_key` similar to the current_user's email is published, a flash message is displayed for that user indicating that he has a new message without refreshing the page. I want behavior similar to Facebook notifications.

The producer code looks like this:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController    
  def create
   @message = Message.new(message_params)
   @message.creator_id = current_user.id
   @message.receiver_id = params[:message][:receiver_id]

   if @message.save
     email = @message.receiver.email
     $message_exchange.publish(@message.content, :routing_key => email)
     redirect_to user_path(current_user)
  end
end
```

The consumer code: looks like this:

```
  email = current_user.email
  $message_queue.bind($message_exchange, :routing_key => email)
  logger.info " [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C"
  $message_queue.subscribe(:manual_ack => true) do |delivery_info, properties, body|
    logger.info " [x] #{delivery_info.routing_key}:#{body}"
    if delivery_info.routing_key == current_user.email
      flash[:notice] = "you have new message: #{body}"
    end
  end
```

The problem is that i don't know where to put the consumer code. I have tried putting the code as a method in the application controller but this does not seem to work. Any suggestion on how to do this better is highly appreciated.

Comment: Controller must push notification to client. Have you looked at [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) or a similar push technology?

Comment: @NicolasLabrot I haven't looked at websocket, just skimming through various google results seems like a good way of implementing this. I will definitely dig deeper into this. thank you